# SQL Server table with different case in PowerShell SMO vs SSMS

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql, ssms, smo

I'm quite confused and not sure where to start looking. I have a tablename that appears in different case sys.object and in the SSMS GUI, as opposed retrieving it via SMO

e.g. in SSMS I see "TABLENAME" but in Smo I see "TableName." This is causing issues with an IBM application and I'm struggling to figure out why this is.

```
$table = $SmoServer.Databases.Item("MyDb").Tables.Item("TABLENAME","dbo")
Write-Output $table
```

Output given is "TableName."

Running a sql query though:

```
select [name] from sys.objects where name = 'TABLENAME'
```

Output given is "TABLENAME."

Not that it should matter but collation is case insensitive.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: It's interesting this would cause an issue, as the SQL language is not supposed to be case sensitive. This sounds more like an issue with the IBM side.

Comment: Both SSMS and SMO use the catalog views so I'd expect to see the same case. Are you sure you're connected to the same server?

Comment: Check you SQL server collation, if it's case sensitive or not, and also check if a table with a same name exists in more than one schema.

Comment: Joel, yes agreed. The application is being difficult but I would still like to understand what's happening, and maybe see if I can find a work around.

Dan. Yes, same server.

Daniel. As above, the collation is case insensitive and no, just the one schema :/

Comment: I can only assume that someone attempted a refactor on the name at some point and some metadata is left incomplete somewhere.

Comment: It turned out this was an issue caused by previous work within my PowerShell session. After restarting, it worked as expected. Just one of those days. Apologies.

Comment: To be more precise... The confusion was caused by using the "Item" method. I'll edit the post to explain.

Comment: Feel free to put the update in an actual answer. SMO is the gift that keeps on giving; thanks for pointing out Yet Another quirk of this marvelous technology. (Yes, I am indeed being sarcastic. SMO is a nice idea in theory that happens to be poorly executed in practice.)

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't sarcastic about the bit where I suggested you self-answer the question, that was sincere. Questions shouldn't contain answers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk of using the Item method to retrieve the table from the SMO Tables object. The first time you retrieve the table, it seems to return the table with the casing provided in the method argument. If I run the Item method again with different casing, it still outputs the casing the first call.

e.g.:

**1st run:**

```
$SmoServer.Databases.Item("MyDb").Tables.Item("TableName","dbo")
```

Will output "TableName" as was provided in the above parameter, even if the table is actually "TABLENAME."

**2nd Run:**

```
$SmoServer.Databases.Item("MyDb").Tables.Item("TableNAME","dbo")
```

Will still output "TableName" even though I changed the casing. It will only output the new casing of "TableNAME" if I recreate the smoServer object.

Interesting behaviour. I think I'll use Where-Object instead.